# How to Run Program Downloaded From GitHub

Tags: debugging, github, visual-studio-2008

I am new to running programs off GitHub.

I have downloaded [Apriori Algorithm](https://github.com/Omar-Salem/Apriori-Algorithm) by Omar Gameel Salem from GitHub. I downloaded the .rar file and extracted it to a folder.

Can anyone can tell how to open the code in .NET and run it using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the .rar to a folder

Open the folder

Look for a file with a .sln extension. (They are normally purple)

Open the .sln

Once Visual Studio loads the project, click Build -> Build Solution

After that, you should be good to go, just click the play button to run the program.